# Having various possible layouts

Tags: java, android, layout, if-statement, spinner

So I'm trying to create an activity that passes some values into another activity and then, depending on those values, chooses one of several different layouts.

I know that the values are passed through fine, but it won't display the layout (or any layout, it just stays on the previous screen). My code is:

```
public class ContactDisplay extends GetContact {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String nameChosen = extras.getString("nameSpinner");
       String addressChosen = extras.getString("addressSpinner");

        if((nameChosen == "Michael") && (addressChosen == "Michaels Address")){
            setContentView(R.layout.contact1_layout);
        }

    }
}
```

I've only set it up to with one of the layouts so far, but it should work if Michael and Michaels Address are chosen. Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
   if((transportItemChosen.equals("Michael")) && (locationItemChosen.equals("Michaels Address"))){
        setContentView(R.layout.contact1_layout);
    }
```

In Java you want to use the equals() function when comparing strings not the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought is that I would try to not use hard coded values for extras because you can misspell something and it is very easy to get stuck ... if that is not the problem then try to make some logs and see what exactly you receive in  `transportItemChosen` and `locationItemChosen`

EDIT:

And yes, to compare two `Objects` you have to use `equals()` method not the == operator.